# UML, Do all state diagrams require input/output labels?

Tags: uml

I have a state diagram which is more of a business process model, than say a representation of a numerical process (e.g. a vending machine). Do I still need to label inputs and outputs, as they are rather guessable from the state labels? I didnt know what the standard UML approach would be.

Thanks

Comment: I thought the main recommendation for UML syntax was "if the audience understands it, it's right".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the purpose of your diagram. If you intend to generate code from it, then the more information you put on the diagram, the more control you have over the generated code. If the diagram is intended to convey information to a human reader, then if the labels are redundant then the diagram might be clearer and easier to read without them.

UML is a tool - you use it to do something, but the diagrams are not (usually) the end product.